# Redirect during upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, redirect

Thinking through my process that I have outlined for a migration from 2010 to a 2013 farm...I'm looking at how I can keep users out of the farm while I do the work of converting the web application to claims mode then doing the site collection upgrade in the 2013 farm.

I've seen articles that talk about either doing no redirect or doing a DNS level redirect but i'm wondering if i can leverage the app_offline.htm process to keep users out...

Would this method cause any issues with these particular stages of my upgrade/migration? maybe this method doesn't make sense though...

Also...alternatively would there be a way to leverage hosts files on my machine and the server to keep things alive for me but not my users until we were ready to make the adjustments in DNS?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the process you talking about But i can tell what we did couple of times.

**Method # 1**

- Mark the Database readonly from SQL server in SharePoint 2010 Farm. Because at this time user accessing the 2010 farm so they can view the things but cant add/delete/modify it.
- Move the database to new farm 2013, upgrade them once everything working then Update the AAM settings & update the DNS.

**Method # 2**

- Remove the AAM Settings
- If you are using the Load Balancer for WFE then remove all servers from Load balancer.
- You will still able to access the site using server name & port number.

Comment: Here are my resources I was looking at for this: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/07/maintenance-page-for-sharepoint-2010.html and http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2012/11/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-preparation.html ... my biggest concern with most the methods is will the site collection upgrade complete properly? Method #1 makes me wonder if in Ready only mode can the site collection upgrade actually run?